# Solution for $2^n = 12k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

How can I find a solution for this problem?

Also, where are some resources to solve a similar problem? I came across this question when attempting to find a solution to $2^n \equiv 0 \mod 12$.

Comment: Can $3$ divide the left hand side?

Comment: To solve a similar problem, review divisibility and prime number decomposition, i.e., $12=2^2\cdot 3$ and $2^n=2\cdots 2$, with $12\mid 2^n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In other words, never, since $2^n$ doesn't contain any $3$'s.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And "resources" are just texts on elementary number theory for this. They all deal with divisibility and prime numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Do you know many powers of $2$ which are multiples of $3$?

Answer (score 2):

If
$$2^n=12k$$
then
$$2^{n-2}=3k$$
$$2^{n-2}\equiv 0 \mod{3}$$
$$(-1)^{n}\equiv 0 \mod{3}$$
$$0\in\{-1,1\}$$
Which is not true - contradicts the original equation.

Comment: Why not just say $3\mid 12$, but $3\nmid 2^n$?

Comment: Well I just proved why $3$ does not divide $2^n$ if it wasn't obvious to the OP.